# Find the minimum of $\sqrt{\cos x+3}+\sqrt{2\sin x+7}$ without derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, inequality

How do we find the minimum of
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\cos x+3}+\sqrt{2\sin x+7}$$
without using derivatives?

This problem is probably related to circles of Apollonius.

I have tried AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality but I can't work it out.

Anyway, I have solved it in a more geometric way. Here's my answer.

Firstly we can do some identical transformation.
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\sqrt{(\cos x+1)^2+(\sin x)^2+4}+\sqrt{(\cos x)^2+(\sin x+2)^2+9})$$

So that it makes sense in geometry.

[image: f(x)]

$P(\cos x,\sin x)$ is on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, and the value of $f(x)$ equals to sum of the distance from $A(0,-2)$ to $P$ and from $B(-1,0)$ to $P$.

In other words:
$$f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\sqrt{|PB|^2+4}+\sqrt{|PA|^2+9}).$$

And here we can use Minkowski inequality.

$$f(x)\geq \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \sqrt{(|PA|+|PB|)^2+25}$$

When $P$,$A$,$B$ is collinear, $RHS$ gets the minimum. Meanwhile, $LHS = RHS$.

Therefore, $f(x)_{min}=\sqrt{15}$.

Comment: The minimum of $f(x)$ is $\sqrt{15}$.

Comment: @Angelo, can you explain how you worked this out?  I'm just really curious.

Comment: I believe it is straightforward to get the minimum **via differentiation** [I don't know for sure though, as I have not checked]. But as clearly stated in the post above, the OP is looking for another, presumably more clever, way to solve this. It is the method that is of interest here.

Comment: From the algebraic-geometry tag description: "This tag should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry." Please be more careful when adding tags in the future.

Comment: Your geometric proof is very nice. A question: How did you choose this form $f(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\sqrt{(\cos x+1)^2+(\sin x)^2+4}+\sqrt{(\cos x)^2+(\sin x+2)^2+9})$ without derivative and without knowing the minimum $\sqrt{15}$? We have many choices such as ($a=1$ is your choice) $$f = \frac{1}{2a}\left(\sqrt{(\cos x + a)^2 + \sin^2 x + 6a - a^2 - 1}
+\sqrt{\cos^2 x + (\sin x + 2a)^2 + 14a - 4a^2 - 1}\right).$$

Comment: @RiverLi, I chose this form because I wanted to make sure that $f(x)$ not only has a geometric meaning but also matches the form of Cauchy-Schwarz or Minkowski inequality. In this way there's possibility of working it out.

Comment: @Nephrenn Interesting. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Nephrenn By the way, if we want to find the minimum of $\sqrt{\cos x + 5} + \sqrt{8\sin x + 176/3}$, we should use the form $$\sqrt{(\cos x + 1/2)^2 + \sin^2 x + 15/4} + \sqrt{\cos^2 x + (\sin x + 4)^2 + 125/3}.$$ Then apply Minkowski to get the minimum $\sqrt{260/3}$. Your approach should help.

Comment: @RiverLi I'm sorry that I couldn't explain it more detailedly since it is the result of a long process of trial and error. What interests me is that the method seems generally applicable.

Comment: @Nephrenn It is surely applicable. But I think it is not easy to determine the appropriate form which is unique determined by the optimal value of the problem, without derivative or without knowing the minimum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a rough idea for a solution (since there are some details I skim over). I'm pretty sure the algebra can be simplified using some AM-GM variation, but I couldn't make it work. Although I'm hopeful that someone else can give a more optimal solution.

Note that for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{align*}
&0 \le(t+2)^2(5t^2+6) =5 t^4 + 20 t^3 + 26 t^2 + 24 t + 24\\
\color{darkblue}{\implies}& 14 t^4 + 8 t^3 + 42 t^2 + 16 t + 28 \ge 9t^4 - 12 t^3 + 16 t^2 - 8 t + 4\\
\color{darkblue}{\implies}&\left(2t^2 +4\right)\left(
4t +7t^2+7\right)\ge (3 t^2 + 2 - 2 t)^2\\
\color{darkblue}{\implies}&2\sqrt{2t^2 +4}\sqrt{4t+7t^2+7} \ge 2\left(3t^2 +2-2t \right)\\
\color{darkblue}{\implies}&2t^2 +4 +2\sqrt{2t^2 +4}\sqrt{4t+7t^2+7} + 4t+7t^2 +7 \ge 15\left(t^2+1\right)\\
\color{darkblue}{\implies}&\left(\sqrt{2t^2 +4} +  \sqrt{4t+7t^2+7}\right)^2 \ge\left( \sqrt{15}\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)^2\\
\color{darkblue}{\implies}&\frac{\sqrt{2t^2+4}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} + \frac{\sqrt{4t+7t^2+7}}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}\ge \sqrt{15}\\
\color{darkblue}{\implies}&\sqrt{\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}+3}\ +\ \sqrt{2\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}+7} \ge \sqrt{15}
\end{align*}

Lastly, notice that under the [half-angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) substitution the problem becomes showing that
$$
\min\left\{\sqrt{\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}+3}\ +\ \sqrt{2\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}+7}\right\} = \sqrt{15}
$$
where $t = \tan(x/2)$. Since $\sqrt{\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}+3}\ +\ \sqrt{\frac{4t}{1+t^{2}}+7}\Bigg\vert_{t=-2} = \sqrt{15}$ we are done.

Comment: How did you note this inequality that solves the problem just right?

Comment: It should come from using the half-angle substitution first to parametrise $\cos x, \sin x$, and then working to square both sides until we arrive at a function which is always nonnegative.

Answer (score 2):

Because $$\sqrt{\cos x+3}+\sqrt{2\sin x+7}=$$
$$=\sqrt{15}+\left(\sqrt{\cos x+3}-2\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}+\frac{5\sqrt5}{24\sqrt3}\left(\cos^2x-\frac{9}{25}\right)\right)+$$
$$+\left(\sqrt{2\sin x+7}-3\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}+\frac{5\sqrt5}{24\sqrt3}\left(\sin^2x-\frac{16}{25}\right)\right)\geq\sqrt{15}.$$
The equality occurs for $(\cos{x},\sin{x})=\left(-\frac{3}{5},-\frac{4}{5}\right).$

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proof but a sequence of heuristic and "nicety" arguments which lead to $\sqrt{15}$.

Let $f(x)$ be the expression to be minimized.

The substitution $\sin(x)\to t$, $\cos(x) \to \pm \sqrt{1-t^2}$ gives

$$f(x(t)) = \sqrt{3-\sqrt{1-t^2}}+\sqrt{2 t+7}$$

where we have taken the minus sign under the square root because this leads to a smaller expression.

Now letting $t\to \frac {p}{q}$ gives

$$f=\frac{1}{\sqrt{q}}
\left(\sqrt{3 q-\sqrt{q^2-p^2}}+\sqrt{2 p+7 q}\right)$$

The second term in the bracket suggests a negative value for $p$ ($q$ can't be negative because of the common factor in front) and the square root term under square root in the first term suggests that $p$ and $q$ might be members of a Pythagorean triple, like e.g. $(3,4,5)$.  This leads us to test $(p,q) = (-4,5)$ or $t=-\frac{4}{5}$ which gives $f=\sqrt {15}$. This is the minumum value of $f$ as other users have shown.